# How to cast a 'list of classes' to a 'list of its interface'?

Tags: c#, class, interface

I need to cast a class list to its own interface list.

So I have interface `Demo_Interface` and two classes based on `Demo_Interface` ,
Now I create list of classes like `List<Test_Class1>`

And I have a function with `List<Demo_Interface>` parameter.

**Here's interface :**

```
       interface Demo_Interface
        {
            int test_int { get; set; }
        }
```

**Here's Entire Code :**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        ///// Main Interface
        interface Demo_Interface
        {
            int test_int { get; set; }
        }

        //// Class 1 Based On Demo_Interface
        class Test_Class1 : Demo_Interface
        {
            public int test_int { get; set; }
            public string test_string { get; set; }

        }
        ///// Class 2 Based On Demo_Interface
        class Test_Class2 : Demo_Interface
        {
            public int test_int { get; set; }
            public string test_string { get; set; }

        }

        //// And Main Class
        class Main_Class
        {
            public List<Test_Class1> class_list_1 { get; set; }

            public List<Test_Class2> class_list_2 { get; set; }

            public Main_Class()
            {
                class_list_1 = new List<Test_Class1>() { };
                class_list_2 = new List<Test_Class2>() { };
            }
        }

        //// Console Main
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var new_main_class = new Main_Class();

            Output_Class(new_main_class.class_list_1); ///// ==> ERROR

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        //// Simple Function for do something with interface
        static void Output_Class(List<Demo_Interface> inter_input)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < inter_input.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}",i, inter_input[i].test_int);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How Can I cast `List<Test_Class1>` to `List<Demo_Interface>` , When **Test_Class1** uses **Demo_Interface**?

Comment: What exception you are getting here...?

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar I was accepting your answer why you deleted it ? it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
List<Test_Class1> testDemo = new List<Test_Class1>(); //list of Test_Class1 instances
List<Demo_Interface> result = testDemo.ToList<Demo_Interface>();
```

This is safe because we are not directly casting testDemo to its interface. We are keeping testDemo as it is and we are creating `result` which is list of `Demo_Interface`

Answer (score 0):

If you need only to enumerate through the `List<Demo_Interface>` like shown in example, you don't have to do any kind of explicit casting. `List<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>` which is [covariant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/variance-in-generic-interfaces) generic type.

> Covariance for collections enables implicit conversion of a collection of a more derived type to a collection of a less derived type

In your case, `List<Test_Class1>` implements `IEnumerable<Test_Class1>`, but since `Test_Class1` implements `Demo_Interface`, you can take advantage of generics variance and write, for example, something like this:

```
IEnumerable<Test_Class1> col = new List<Test_Class1>();
IEnumerable<Demo_Interface> colImplicit = col;
```

That basically means that your `Output_Class` method can take `IEnumerable<Demo_Interface>` argument and you'll be able to pass both lists without casting them explicitly using `Cast<T>` or creating a new collection using `ToList<T>`.

```
private void Output_Class(IEnumerable<Demo_Interface> inter_input)
{
    // do your thing
}

// Method invocation
Output_Class(new_main_class.class_list_1);
```

Comment: Thank you for your method,I accepted @PrasadTelkikar answer for it's more simple way.

Comment: Sure, just take into account that `ToList<Demo_Interface>` will create a new object, which can be easily checked using `object.ReferenceEquals(testDemo, result)` - returns false, or using `GetHashCode()` on each object - returns different values

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cast a `List<ClassThatImplementsInterface>` as a `List<IInterfaceItImplements>`.

If you could, and you did this:

```
var classList = new List<ClassThatImplementsInterface>();
var interfaceList = (List<IInterfaceItImplements>)classList;
```

... then you would be able to do this:

```
interfaceList.Add(new SomeOtherClassThatImplementsTheInterface);
```

But casting the list doesn't create a new list. In the above example there aren't two lists. There are two variables with references to the same list. If you could cast as seen above, you would be able to define a list of one type and add a completely different type to it. The compiler prevents that.

You could

- create a new `List<IDemoInterface>` and add the items to it. (Or an array, IEnumerable, etc.)
- Leave the list as-is, and just cast individual items when/if you need to. In most cases we wouldn't need to cast something as an interface it implements.

If we need to cast a whole collection as a different type, it's likely because we're passing it as an argument.

That's actually a good reason *not* to define a method argument as a collection type like a `List<T>` which can be modified unless it's our intent to modify the collection.

That's one reason why we pass less-specific collection types, like `IEnumerable<T>`.

Suppose the method argument looks like this:

```
void MethodINeedToPassTheArgumentTo(IEnumerable<IDemoInterface> items)
```

Now we can take our `List<TestClass>` and do this:

```
MethodINeedToPassTheArgumentTo(testClassList.Cast<IDemoInterface>);
```

We're not creating a new collection. We're passing a reference that allows the other method to view the items in the list, each *individually* cast as `IDemoInterface`. For practical purposes it *looks* to the other method like a collection of `IDemoInterface`, and that's okay because the other item can't modify the collection. It can't attempt to add other types into the `List<TestClass>`.

Comment: thank you for great explaining , So how @PrasadTelkikar solution works fine ?

Comment: Because it's not casting the list as another list. It's creating a new `List<IDemoInterface>` and putting all the items from the first list in the second list. That's okay. When we "cast" something we aren't creating a new object. We're just referring to the existing object as a different type it implements. We can only cast something as what it already is. But we can take an existing object and use it to create a new object.

Comment: I feel creating new list with only required fields is safer than casting it

Comment: Creating a new list is safer. Any sort of cast that isn't safe or isn't even possible is prevented by the compiler, which is why it's not allowing you to cast it.